# Nodejs OPC-UA server certificat error without using any tls or certificates

Tags: node.js, opc-ua

I do create an opc-ua server like this:

```
var opcOptions = {
        hostname: options.opcHost || "127.0.0.1",
        port: options.opcPort || 4334,
        resourcePath: options.opcName || "opcua",
        buildInfo: {
            productName: "OPCUA",
            buildNumber: "0.1",
            buildDate: new Date()
        }
    }

    var server = new opcua.OPCUAServer(opcOptions);
```

But this will somehow spawn this error message in the console:

```
10:45:20.058Z :verify                        :48    [NODE-OPCUA-W06] The certificate subjectAltName does not match the server applicationUri
 ...                                                Please regenerate a specific certificate that matches your server applicationUri
 ...                                                certificate subjectAltName  = urn:DESKTOP-6B2NRGG:NodeOPCUA-Server
 ...                                                server applicationUri  = urn:WIN01:NodeOPCUA-Server
 ...                                                certificateFile         = C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\node-opcua-default-nodejs\Config\PKI\own\certs\certificate.pem
```

Any idea on how to ignore/disable this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `node-opcua` does create some kind of certificate that is used for the server even if the server does not use tls. And after I run my software for the first time that certificate was created with the current hostname of my computer. Not long ago I did change my hostname so this certificate was not valid anymore.

The location of those files is `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\node-opcua-default-nodejs`.

Deleting the whole folder will prompt node-opcua to recreate them with all certificates at software start and after that the error message was gone.

Answer (score 1):

The `NODE-OPCUA-W06` warning indicates that the server certificate doesn't match the Server settings (applicationUri and host name mainly).
When this happens, this leads to hard to find connectivity issues, as clients that are strictly verifying the server certificate will reject the connection, suspecting a certificate mismatch.

The best approach is not to ignore the warning but fix the problem.

In most of the case, this can be done by deleting the certificate file pointed in the warning message and restarting the server.

A new default certificate will be automatically regenerated with the correct information.

However in secure industrial environment certificates are generated by an certificate authority. In this case, the certificate has to be regenerated by the external app .

The book [NodeOPCUA by Example Edition 2024](https://leanpub.com/node-opcuabyexample-edition2024) contains a section about NodeOPCUA based Server using a custom Certificate management that could be interesting to read in this regards.

For those who are concerned about the OPC UA communication security and want a programmatic control of the server certificate using [Push and Pull certificate management](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/GDS/v105/docs/7) in their NodeOPCUA  server can  request a dedicate GDS library for NodeOPCUA to the author of the library